# Export raster file geodatabase to jp2 or jpeg?

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, export, file-geodatabase

Can I export or copy a raster from a file Geodatabase and create a output to jpeg or jp2000 formate? I was reading two different helpline on ArcGIS 10.1 and wasn't sure if I was supposed to export jp2000 from another file geodatabase to file geodatabase.

I tried to do that the other day but it failed. Don't know if it was the space was issued or maybe I wasn't doing the proper way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  There is an image analysis window in ArcMap that allows you to select images, process and alter them if need be, and save as a different format.  [Here is the link to the window](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000006q000000). And [here is a link on what conversions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000062000000) you can do.

Comment: Thank you evv_gis for replying ! I'll review them before what I do.